# Swift: how to maximize warnings in Xcode? What is the equivalent for -Wall in swiftc?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a number of Swift-only framework targets within a big iOS app project. I would like to explore the strictness of Swift compiler options to understand if they could give any additional benefits.

There are many warnings in Xcode but most of them seem to be Clang-related. What is the equivalent of `-Wall` or `-Weverything` that we could do for Swift compiler?

One example is a warning to prevent shadowing of the local variables: `Apple LLVM 9.0 - Warnings - All languages / Hidden local variables`: it is `GCC_WARN_SHADOW = YES` under the hood so it does not affect the `swiftc` compiler.

Comment: Which language? Both `-Wall` and `-Weverything` should work for LLVM.

Comment: I am asking about Swift.

Comment: What specific warning are you looking for? Swift is a type-safe language. Something that would trigger a warning in C/C++/Obj-C is usually explicitly forbidden in Swift and it will trigger an error.

Comment: If you go into the Build Settings tab in your project settings in Xcode and scroll to "Swift Compiler - Warning Policies", there are only 2 options - "Suppress Warnings" and "Treat warnings as errors".

Comment: Thanks Sweeper, I did that already. I am wondering if there are any other options. Example for Clang: -Weverything has many more flags than is listed in Xcode. I am wondering if there is some similar flag for swiftc.

Comment: `What specific warning are you looking for?` -

I have added one example that goes beyond type safety.

Comment: Warnings for shadowing are still under discussion within SE. It is unclear currently what best practice should be. I have my own opinions, but it's difficult to nail down precisely enough to detect automatically because of how it intermixes with other common Swift practices. https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1687

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. C accumulated layer-upon-layer of warnings and then barnacles like "warnings that aren't part of 'all warnings'" over many years and many compilers, coupled with a language that allows a lot of things you generally should never do.

Swift is young and has broken backward compatibility several times in its short life. It hasn't been around long enough to need bizarre backward-compatibilty options yet. Many of the things C adds as warnings, Swift just makes illegal or requires you make explicit.

That said, there absolutely are other layers of warnings that exist already. The first set are found via the static analyzer (Cmd-Shift-B in Xcode), and the second exist in tools like [swiftlint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) which fills the same role as linters in C. The line between a linter and a compiler warning is vague and shifting, and you may see some things move from the linter to the compiler over time. But I still doubt you'll ever see a warning system as convoluted as GCC's (which Clang inherited).

Comment: Thanks, Rob. Your answer is something I expected.